# Sort by relevance using YouTube API in Python

Tags: python, api, youtube, rank

I've been trying to create a YouTube Rank Checker in python. The idea is it searches on YouTube for a keyword and checks what position the video is.

The only problem is it isn't returning accurate results. For instance if I search for "dog video" and my video is position 3 when I search using the normal website and the API returns it as position 17. I was thinking this could be because it's sorting the results differently (It should be sorting by relevance) but I can't figure out how to chance the sort order.

If anyone can provide any help, even if it's just pointing out something obvious in my code I would appreciate it very much, thank you for your help in advance.

Here's my code:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from optparse import OptionParser
import time

# Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the "API key" value from the "Access" tab of the
# Google APIs Console http://code.google.com/apis/console#access
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
DEVELOPER_KEY = "devkey"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
videos = []
channels = []
playlists = []
videoids = []
videoidskeys = {"cat video":"ZBAGEeOms-8", "dog video":"nGeKSiCQkPw", "testing video":"GAyni_fKKLg"}
videokeys = videoidskeys.keys()

def checkrank(videoid, keyword):
  time.sleep(6)
  if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--q", dest="q", help="Search term",
      default=keyword)
    parser.add_option("--max-results", dest="maxResults",
      help="Max results", default=25)
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=options.maxResults,
  ).execute()

  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    videoids.append(search_result["id"]["videoId"])
  count = 0

  for videoid1 in videoids:
    count = count+1
    if videoid1 == videoid:
      return "Keyword: %s - Rank: %s" % (keyword, count)
      count = 0


for video in videokeys:
  print checkrank(videoidskeys[video],video)
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, here's the working code in case anyone wants it:

http://pastebin.com/Vei3FyUz

Also YouTube personalizes results if you're logged in, so be sure to log out when checking accuracy.

Comment: The pastebin link has expired. It should have been in the post itself.